# Why are my Android fragments' layouts offset by the height of the navbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

All my Android fragment layouts seem to be offset by the navbar height. This also means they get covered at the bottom by the tab bar. What am I doing wrong?

Examples:
[image: Centred label not centred]
[image: Space at top and hidden at bottom]

I'm not sure what code you want to see; most of it came straight out of Android Studio. And apparently I can't post it all here at once - "It looks like your post is mostly code." :(

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sample fragment: fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.carnival.CarnivalFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exchange `android:layout_height="match_parent"` set for `<fragment` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`, allow constraints to to their job, attach fragment above bottom nav. currently looks like `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"` isn't making your `Fragment` appear above bottom nav, instead its fulfilling whole `Activity`, even space under bottom nav

top spacing is probably introduced by `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` line set for root element, just remove this line

btw. there is a dev option ["show layout bounds"](https://whyingo.org/how-to-enable-or-disable-show-layout-bounds-android/), it will show you where your views/fragments are placed

Comment: Setting layout_height=0dp just makes the label disappear completely (hidden under the navbar?). I'll try showing layout bounds.

Comment: try to remove `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`, maybe thats the only reason for your problem and `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` works well (but as you noticed on last screen, you can't scroll to last element, is placed under bottom nav)

Comment: Ok, taking out `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` seems to have worked. I guess that line is needed when the action bar can be on top of the view..?

Comment: it is needed when you are NOT using "default" `ActionBar` (theme extending some `NoActionBar`), instead you are using custom [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/appbar/setting-up#add-toolbar) placed in your XML. I don't see custom `Toolbar` in your layout, but I can see on screens, so currently you are using "default" one and then using `?attr/actionBarSize` isn't needed, theme of `Activity` is adding it by own